# User Identity is null using JWT Authorization on SignIn

Tags: angularjs, authentication, oauth, jwt

I am stuck on this problem. I use angular for client side and mvc with EF on server side. I want to protect my Dashboard Controller with Authorize attribute. So to make it clear, when i got my dashboard controller with [Authorize] attribute and i sign up .... i get instantly redirected to login page because  User.Identity is null. I noticed in chrome developer tools that it didnt sent Bearer token with request.

When i remove authorize attribute from Dashboard controller and i want to fire any of my protected API controllers with [Authorize] attribut and even with roles protection, everything works fine, because in every request i see my Bearer token to be sent and my User.Identity is fulfilled with credentials.

Am i missing something like Controllers cant receive Bearer jwt tokens and ApiControllers can? I am stuck on it for more than 6h and cant figure out, why when i want to get on my protected Dashboard controller, my token is not sent, but whenever i want to use any other controller and method, everything is ok

```
    [CustomAuthorize]
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    // GET: Dashboard
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I created CustomAuthorize class to see if i got something in User.Identity, but everything is null

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/");
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (this.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            this.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my startup method where i force controllers to validate jwt token

```
 private void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        var issuer = "http://localhost:2969";
        string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];
        byte[] audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"]);

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
                IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                {
                    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
                }
            });
    }
```

Main angular module with routing and interceptor to push my token into every request

```
var app = angular.module(moduleName, ["ngRoute", "ngResource", 'ui.bootstrap', "signalR" ])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $compileProvider, $httpProvider) {
    'use strict';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/javascript';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', 'currentUser', '$location', function ($q, currentUser) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                //if (currentUser.profile.loggedIn) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + currentUser.profile.Token;
                //}
                return config;
            },
            'responseError': function (response) {
                if (response.status == 401 || response.status == 403) {
                    window.location = "/";
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    }]);

    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true);
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "app/components/views/index.html"
    })
```

Comment: I managed to to get Authorization bearer token into Request Header but still when it reach my Custom Authorization its still null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i figured out that Register method of WebApiConfig class it somehow those two methods delete header content

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //Delete both of those methods to make JWT authentication accept JWT tokens, at least it was the problem in my case
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

    }
}
```